# What is a combinatorial proof for $p_k(n) \leq (n-k+1)^{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Suppose $p_k(n)$ is the number of partitions of the integer $n$ into $k$ parts. For example, the partition of 5 into 2 parts is; $p_2(5) = 2$, since the partitions are (4,1) and (3,2).

What is a good combinatorial proof that $p_k(n) \leq (n-k+1)^{k-1}$ for $k \leq n$? Or must this be done algebraically?

Comment: what's $p_k(n)$?

Comment: Updated the question to include the definition.

Comment: $p_k(n)$ is the [Stirling number of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Lower_and_upper_bounds).

Comment: @GAVD No, it isn't. The Stirling number of the second kind counts partitions of **sets**, $p_k(n)$ counts [partitions of **numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extremely straightforward way to see this:

A $k$-partition of $n$ is uniquely determined by the first $k-1$ values.  Each element of a $k$-partition must be at most $n-k+1$, since the other elements are positive integers and sum to $\ge k-1$.  Therefore the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts is no larger than the number of $(k-1)$-tuples of integers between $1$ and $n-k+1$.